# How to group by month by providing a start date and an end date?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS month, sum(points) from table_name group by month;
```

I am getting the sum of points but the result is not consistent with the result I get when I try by a date range . Eg,

```
select sum(points) from table_name where '2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= date(created_at) <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59';
```

The result of Jan, 2015 by 1st and 2nd query above are not same. Where is the problem in the first query?

Comment: I guess you are not using right criteria in your second query try something like `where created_at  between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I think you should read this: ["What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?", by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @Barranka sure i will read it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're writing your second query is not valid. You can only use binary expressions, so your query should be like this:

```
select sum(points) 
from table_name 
where '2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= date(created_at)
  and date(created_at) <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59';
```

In your original form, the where is being evaluated like this (I think):

- First: `'2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= date(created_at)`

  Assuming this is true, this would be evaluated as `1`
- Second: `'2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= date(created_at) <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'`,

  but this is equivalent to `1 <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'`, so... it's of course not what you want

Comment: Yes, I got it. The other way to write is like --                                              select sum(points) from table_name where date(created_at) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'

Comment: @Goku__ I recommend you read ["What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common" by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)